# Can I use more than one encryption program to encrypt my computer files or will it cause conflicts?

Tags: encryption, disk-encryption, file-encryption

I encrypted my Ubuntu Linux Operating System in the installation process using the default encryption in Ubuntu if my computer is encrypted with one program can it be encryption with another at the same time or will that cost errors?

Comment: If you encrypted it with ubuntu ( I assume you mean some kind of full disk encryption), what other encryption programming are you considering? Another full disk encryption mechanism, or encrypting individual files?

Comment: Aside from the question - your username appears to break the page design a wee bit. I have asked on meta whether anything can be done, but it may be simpler just to shorten your username. Just a thought.

Comment: I should of ask the question more like this can I do a full disk encryption and a individual file encryption at the same time

Comment: Multiple low-level solutions could conflict, like running bitlocker + Truecrypt. But running FDE + using filesystem encryption + using encryption tools in userspace would work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean the filesystem is encrypted, this provides protection when your computer is off or logged out, as an attacker would need to decrypt to gain access to files.

It does not provide protection once the machine is logged in to your account - as the decryption happens as part of normal usage, so if you have files you wish to protect from attack on the system when it is logged in, encrypting them is a good idea. This type of attack could be shoulder surfing, where someone gets your password by watching you type it.

Every layer of encryption will add to the time it takes to access the files, so you need to look at your threat model and requirements.